# How to open multiple man pages in split in vim?

Tags: vim, configuration

From [View man pages in Vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/View_man_pages_in_Vim), I learnt how to open `man` pages in `vim` by adding the following lines to `~/.vimrc`:

```
" Enable viewing man page in vim by ":Man ..."
runtime ftplugin/man.vim
" Set keyword 'K' to use ":Man ..." to view man pages in vim
set keywordprg=:Man
```

However, this can only work for one `Man` per `tab`. What I want is to open different `Man` pages in different splits.

Comment: `man.vim` contains code to reuse a existing "man" window. Copy `ftplugin/man.vim` into your personal setup and change it.

Comment: If you split in an existing man pane, the next `:Man` command only affects that pane

Comment: @Thor That is awesome!

Comment: @Thor Can you make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one manual window, all `:Man` commands affect that window. However if you split the window, any `:Man` command will affect the current or last used manual window.